# How to get Decimal instead of Decimal128 in a dictionary marked with [BsonExtraElements]

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

**Update**

Here's some more information about my application business logic, based on @aman's observation that *"it should be possible for you to pull out those elements from the dictionary that your business code depends on and have them represented by their well-defined properties"*.

The relevant part of the application is a registry of (financial) products. The application allows power users to define additional fields on the products and also define limited business logic. E.g. they may define a field called `RiskValue` of type `decimal` and a `RiskColor` of type `string` and a piece of business logic that could say

*If RiskColor is greater than 1.5 then RiskColor should be "Red"*

Now, this business logic needs to be able to cast `RiskColor` to `decimal` in order to perform the comparison and that's where the problem arises.

Based on the definitions above, it would be possible to generate a class at runtime, something like:

```cs
public class Product 
{
    public decimal RiskValue { get; set; }
    public string RiskColor { get; set; }
    public void BusinessLogic( )
    {
        if( RiskValue > 1.5M)
            RiskColor = "Red";
    }
```

But I'm not sure I want to go that route.

---

I have some model classes (in C#) where some properties are not known at compile time. So I have a

```
[BsonExtraElements]
IDictionary<string,object> ExtraElements {get;}
```

(actually BsonExtraElements comes through a convention, but I don't think that matters).

Some of these properties are of type `System.Decimal`, e.g.

```
obj.ExtraElements["PropertyX"] = 1.000M;
```

When I save the object to MongoDB, it gets serialized like this:

```
{
    ...
    "PropertyX" : NumberDecimal("1.000"),
}
```

which is what I expect.

However, when I read the object back into my model, the value of the property is of type `MongoDB.Bson.Decimal128` instead of the expected `System.Decimal`.

Most of the application (except the data layer) is agnostic about the underlying storage mechanism, which is also why I am registering the `[BsonExtraElements]` via a convention instead of via the attribute (the assembly containing my model doesn't have a reference to the MongoDB driver). I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to litter my code with MongoDB specific code. I'm hoping there is a flag I missed, or perhaps some way to make a custom convention to fix it at the driver level.

For now I have solved the issue by implementing `IDictionary<string,object>`in a class called `ExtraElementsDictionary` and passing the value through this method on every action:

```cs
private static object FixValue( object value )
{
    if( value == null ) return null;
    if( value.GetType( ).FullName == "MongoDB.Bson.Decimal128" )
    {
        return decimal.TryParse( value.ToString( ), out var dec ) ? dec : default;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I also considered doing it at the data layer, something like

```cs
public MyModel GetMyModelById(string id) 
{
    // actual retrieval of object
    FixDecimal128(obj.ExtraElements);
    return obj;
}
```

But there must be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:

1. Since you do not want the business logic to become aware of the underlying types that your database library uses, I imagine that you also have concretely defined use for those values for which such a stipulation exists otherwise it would not make much sense.

   In such a case, it should be possible for you to pull out those elements from the dictionary that your business code depends on and have them represented by their well-defined properties. In my view, that would be the cleanest approach:

```
public decimal ValueThatMyBusinessCodeUses { get; set; }
```

2. You can also consider using a custom serializer for your dictionary objects in a globally-applied manner as:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer<IDictionary<string, object>>(new CustomDictionarySerializer());
```

In regards to how to implement your dictionary serializer, have a look at the MongoDB documentation on [Serialization](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/serialization/).

3. Another approach is to have a custom type based mapping as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41881880/2592326) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458792/2592326)

---

There are various helper methods in the MongoDB library that allow casting between the C# types and the BSON class types that MongoDB uses.

If you have a `MongoDB.Bson.Decimal128` based value, you can simply cast it to decimal as follows:

```
Decimal128 value = 2.4M;

decimal result = (decimal)value;
```

If you have a `MongoDB.Bson.BsonDecimal128` based value, you can do the following:

```
BsonDecimal128 value = new BsonDecimal128(2.4M);

decimal result = value.AsDecimal;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way where my business code does not need to be aware of the underlying storage tech each time I use a value. I'll update the issue to clarify.

Comment: Update: I agree that the best solution would be to have the properties concretely defined, I have updated my post to clarify why that is not an option. Thanks for the links, I think a custom serializer would do the trick

Comment: @ThomasM.H. I noticed the updated remark in your question and I feel that likes of `RiskValue` and `RiskColor` have more to do with the presentation/view of your application rather than some model logic itself. I suppose that your program will be pulling the data from the database to show that to the users, and you can, on the presentation layer, parse such coloring rules on the client-side to give the view a better look. The serialization of the `MongoDB.Decimal128` will get you a proper decimal value on the client side itself when you have to deserialize it.

Comment: `RiskColor` was a bad example, I agree that is a presentation issue and it wasn't an actual example, The actual fields has names like `SensitivityToUnderlyingAssetPriceDelta`.

But still - our application(s) allows our users to define a field, import data to the field, define business logic for fields, create a web service, a web presentation and a feed based on the fields, all without involving a developer. It's dynamic all the way through, without there ever being a `SensitivityToUnderlyingAssetPriceDelta` property in the C# code.